# background image to app giving me error

Tags: android, android-layout

I wanted to put background image to my app.

I kept image in res>drawable-hdpi folder.

Seted my image view as:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/tv_un"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="10pt"
android:textColor="#444444"            
    android:orientation="vertical" >


     <ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
android:src="res/drawable-hdpi/capture.PNG"/>
```

But its giving me error in the form of tooltip on line:

> error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'src' with value
>   'res/drawable-hdpi/capture.PNG').

Am i pasting image in wrong folder?

Or code is wrong??

Please help me.

Comment: android:src="res/drawable-hdpi/capture.PNG"/ sould not add .png

Comment: android:src="@drawable/capture this only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
android:src="res/drawable-hdpi/capture.PNG"
```

with

```
android:src="@drawable/capture"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: yeah, worked, just change ur answer to drawable, by mistake written rawable

Answer (score 2):

try this, put capture.png in any drawable folder

```
android:src="@drawable/capture"
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
android:src="res/drawable-hdpi/capture.PNG"
```

with

```
android:src="@drawable/capture"
```

Answer (score 1):

`android:src="@drawable/capture"`

put this.